# PHP - read file and echo results

Tags: php, dir, opendir

I have /fonts/ folder full of .js files.

I know how to read this folder and list all the files there:

> ```
>  $dir = "/fonts"; 
>         if (is_dir($dir)) {     
>             if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
>                 while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
>                     echo '<tr><td>'. $file .'</td></tr>';
>                 }
>             closedir($dh);
>             }
>         }
> ```

But I don't want to write filenames but data they store.

The pattern inside looks like this:

NameOfTheFontFile_400_font.js:

> (...) "font-family":"NameOfTheFont" (...)

So how to modify my first script to open-read each file and grab the font-family name instead of file name?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

```
$lines = file($file);
```

**Edit:** This can probably be optimized, but to get the line with the font:

```
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
  if (strpos($line, 'font-family') !== false)
  {
    echo $line;
  }
}
```

You can dig further in that line using string functions or regular expressions to get the exact font name (using for example [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)), but how to do that depends on the general format of the file.

Comment: I know how to open a file, but I'm not sure how to grab exact word.

Comment: @anonymous I have added some more details to get the right line.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `readfile()` to echo it's output. Also note that this is not tested, but it should work:

```
$dir = "/fonts"; 
    if (is_dir($dir)) {     
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                echo '<tr><td>';
                readfile($file);
                echo '</td></tr>';
            }
        closedir($dh);
        }
    }
```

If your .js file has extra data beside the font name, you do do something like this to find the file name:

```
$dir = "/fonts"; 
    if (is_dir($dir)) {     
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                $lines = file($file);   
                foreach ($lines as $line) {
                    if (preg_match('/("font-family":)(".+")/', $line, $parts) ) {                   
                        echo '<tr><td>', $parts[2], '</td></tr>';   
                    }
                }
            }
        closedir($dh);
        }
    }
```

**Off-topic**: Why are you storing the font's names inside .js files? It would be better to store them inside a xml file or in a DB, because that's what they are made for.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php , you can use file_get_contents to get the contents of files using the filenames you got from directory listing.

`string file_get_contents ( string$filename [, bool$use_include_path = false [, resource $context [, int $offset = 0 [, int $maxlen ]]]] )`

NOTE: Others have already answered the question in detail. Edited this answer in response to sel-fish's comment to elaborate on the linked documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
$dir = '/fonts';

$files = array_filter(glob("$dir/*"), 'is_file');
$contents = array_map('file_get_contents', $files);
foreach ($contents as $content) {
        if (preg_match('#"font-family":"([^"]+)"#', $content, $matches)) {
                echo '<tr><td>'.htmlspecialchars($matches[1]).'</td></tr>';
        }
}
```

Or in a different style:

```
$files = glob("$dir/*");
foreach($files as $file) {
        if (is_file($file)) {
                $content = file_get_contents($file);
                if (preg_match('#"font-family":"([^"]+)"#', $content, $matches)) {
                        echo '<tr><td>'.htmlspecialchars($matches[1]).'</td></tr>';
                }
        }
}
```